# delete a table form a database using laravel command

Tags: php, laravel, database

i need to delete a database table using laravel artisan command .
not like this command **php artisan migrate:rollback --step=5**

i need to create like this route or controller code .

Route::get('/clear/database', function () {

```
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    return redirect('/');
```

});

. i also try
public function dd()

```
{
    Schema::drop('table_name');
}
```

but it not working . gives me error like this **SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (SQL: drop table `table_name`)**

no foreign key for the table .
what should i do ?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

it's because one of your tables has a fk that is pointing to the table you are trying to delete

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0');

Schema::dropIfExists('table');

// or

Artisan::call('command');

DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1');
```